# Where are Mail.app display prefs?

Tags: macos, mail.app, restore, preferences

I restarted my Mac (OS X 10.11.6) this morning and upon opening Mail.app (9.3), most (all?) of my display preferences had been reset. Very annoying! I have a Time Machine backup - what file(s) do I need to restore to get Mail back to where I like it? Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist` - restoring that did the trick.

Comment: love too wait 2 days to mark my answer

Answer (score 0):

`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist` would be the first one to try.